# Automatically vanishing/ blending messagebox popup in MFC

Tags: mfc, popup

I have a CScrollview window.I have added copy-to-Clipboard functionality with doubleclick. But user does not know if it is happening or not. So I want to add a message box but that automatically vanishes or blends, so that user doesn't have to click OK button or anything. But I don,t want to make the popup or the vanishing of it too abrupt. I have no idea how to do it. Can I draw a BMP/PNG image and increase its transparency or something like that?
Anyone please guide me to the way to achieve it.

Note: my application is for xp/win7.

Comment: Is spalshscreen ok to do this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From VS2008 SP1 upward take a look at the `CMFCDesktopAlertWnd` class ([MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983515%28v=vs.90%29.aspx))

Quoting from the **Remarks** section on MSDN (my emphasis)

> A desktop alert window can be transparent, it can appear with animation effects, and it can disappear (**after a specified delay** or when the user dismisses it by clicking the close button).